Ошибка CORS referer в Geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x
Настроил apiKey - указал referer ИМЯ_МОЕГО_САЙТА.RU
В клиентском коде, вызываю загрузку https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x?apikey=МОЙ-АП-КЛЮЧ&format=json&geocode=%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%20%D0%B3' from origin 'https://ИМЯ_МОЕГО_САЙТА.RU
Получаю ошибку:
Access to fetch at 'https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x?apikey=МОЙ-АП-КЛЮЧ&format=json&geocode=%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%20%D0%B3' from origin 'https://ИМЯ_МОЕГО_САЙТА.RU' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x?apikey=МОЙ-АП-КЛЮЧ&format=json&geocode=%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%20%D0%B3:1

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (Gateway Timeout)

Инфо системы:
ОС - windows 10
Браузер - Yandex Версия 24.7.2.1098 (64-bit)
Код запускается через HttpClient из Angular 18 такая же проблема и со стандартным fetch
Вообще не понимаю, что от меня требуется.
Заголовок referer соответствует ИМЯ_МОЕГО_САЙТА.RU

504 это ошибка сервера. Попробуйте ещё раз попозже. Если не починилось пишите в техподдержку

т.к. я запускал это дело из под клиента Angular (HttpClient) - в моём interceptor`е запросов всегда передавался параметр withCredentials: true . Убрал, стали проходить запросы.

т.к. я запускал это дело из под клиента Angular (HttpClient) - в моём interceptor-е запросов всегда передавался параметр withCredentials: true.
Убрал, и стали проходить запросы.
